# Updating overview map in Layout View of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, data-driven-pages

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I am currently working on changing the data driven pages for a map that was last updated years ago. The project requires me making new data driven pages covering a wider area. Part of the legend that I imported from the previous layout (which otherwise needs nothing else changed) is an overview of the map showing the prior grid pattern which was used to make the data driven pages years ago. I have created a new grid pattern to encompass the whole area, but the overview in the legend still only has the old layout, but shows the current data driven page I am looking at (red rectangle) despite it not being part of the grid.

How can I update this overview to represent the changes I have made in the grid pattern for the data driven pages?

[image: Overview]

Comment: What is the data source of the index layer in your main dataframe?  What is the data source of that grid which looks like it is in a separate overview dataframe?  I suspect they are different, but if not, then does the latter have a definition query on it?

Comment: It looks like someone has converted the features to graphics long ago as a 'bigger hammer' approach to some niggling problem... activate the frame and see if you can select the items with the graphic pointer from the drawing toolbar - not the editor wedge or select features pointer. If the features are graphics then you'll need to delete them and rework that data frame with your new grid *or* continue the deception (bad choice, but quicker) and copy/paste some of the boxes so that they're reasonably close to what the grid looks like.

Comment: You can set a 'page definition' once data driven pages is enabled.  You'll need a common attribute between the two grids for the query to work (i.e. if you have grid_id in both grids, you can set the page definition to grid_id).  Page definition is in the definition query tab of layer properties (only when ddp is enabled)